# Time representation in excel above 24 hours

Tags: excel, time

Is there a way to represent a time value in Excel where hours can be 24 and above?

For example, have a time that would be 25:00:00 for 1 AM on the following day (common representation in mass transit scheduling).

It can't just be plain text, because I want to be able to perform calculations on them (averages, standard deviation for example) or chart them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's already the case that if you put a date *or* a time into a cell, you get a datetime value.

For example, type `14:00` into `A1` and `A2`, and set `A3` to `=A1+A2`. Why does it display `04:00`, you might wonder. The answer comes if you set the cell *format* to something that displays date *and* time, eg `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`. Do this to `A1` and `A2` as well and we see:

- entered pure time values are stored as a datetime with the entered time portion, and a date portion of January 0, 1900
- doing math on datetimes is possible and becomes comprehensible once you know that **zero** corresponds to midnight on January 0, 1900, and that **one** unit = 1 day

So to do what you want - to store 25 hours in a cell and have it understood by both users and Excel to mean 25 hours - just put a value of `25/24`, and a custom format including the magic format code `[h]`, the `[]` here meaning 'allow the displayed value to go over 24'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do math in a spreadsheet?  If so, formatting the result of a function as a "Time" can tell you how many hours/days/appropriate units are between two dates.  However, you can't then perform functions on these as you usually would.  A solution might be to format intermediate values as "numbers," use your functions, and then format the final results as "Time."

Comment: I'm outputting the result of a query to Excel for later manipulation by the user. So yes, math might happen. Still, I fear writing the intermediate value as numbers, as you say (so basically the number of seconds after midnight) might be my only possibility.