# How can I sum a column of large hours:mins:seconds figures in excel?

Tags: excel

Using MS Excel 2010.

A column of hours, mins, secs e.g.

```
12345:34:34
12345:34:34
12345:34:34
```

Is totalled as

```
00000:00:00
```

The cells' format is set to [h]:mm:ss

Can anyone suggest a way of getting the correct answer please?
I've tried =a1+a2+a3 as well as =sum(a1:a3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this formula and format the result as [h]:mm:ss ...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(":",A1:A3)-1)/24+REPLACE(A1:A3,1,FIND(":",A1:A3)-1,0))
```

Comment: Glad this helped. Perhaps a simpler alternative would be to replace text values with serial numbers so instead of `12345:34:34`, enter `=12345/24+"0:34:34"`. These values can then just be summed normally.

Answer (score 3):

`12345:34:34` is not a valid time, [because it is more than 9999:59:59](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx).

If you do want to add those times, I think you need to do it manually. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943906/timespan-in-excel-above-24-hours) for example.

In your case, you could use decimal values: `12345:34:34 = 12345 + 34/60 + 34/3600` hours. Then add and convert back to a string.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It appears to work for smaller values e.g. 45:30:30 three times is correctly summed. I couldn't work out why it fails when the values get larger. And 12345:34:34 is a perfectly valid time - it's the number of hours a machine has worked since we started measuring it. Perhaps the format is wrong, but the time is right.

Comment: What I meant by not valid was from an excel perspective, not in general. I understand that 12345 hours is about 1.5 years and is a valid time.

Comment: @Pete Actually [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) says that the limit is 9999:59:59.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your research. There is something weird though because I can add 9999:59:59 to 45:45:45 and get a correct answer.

Comment: Excel doesn't recognise 10,000 hours or larger `as an input value` (as already mentioned), it treats such values as text....but it happily sums smaller values to give valid time value results greater than 10,000 hours which is why lori_m's solution will give you a valid time value

Answer (score 0):

The formula you created with AutoSum is fine.

All you need do is apply an appropriate format to its result:

Select the cell containing the total
From the Format menu, choose the Cells command
From the Category list, select Custom
In the Type box, input the format h:mm
(note the use of square brackets).
If you want to show seconds in your total, input 
Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot simpler just to SUM(a1:a3) and then format the cell with custom format [h]:mm:ss      You don't have to create a hairy formula or anything.