# VBA - Subtracting hours

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excell sheet and I need to subtract two cells wich contain time values: **18:35 - 18:02**. However, when I subtract these two values I get the following result: 12:33:00 AM. What I need to get is just the 00:33:00. In other words, the difference in minutes between these two times.
My code is as follows:

```
Sub calculo_setup()

Dim x As Date
Dim col As Integer
Dim lin As Integer
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim prouzido As Integer
Dim programado As Integer


lin = 3
col = 5

Sheets("Dados").Select
Cells(7, col - 1).Select

start_time = ActiveCell

MsgBox start_time, , "A hora de início é"

Call organiza_autoclv

Sheets("Dados").Select
Cells(3, col).Select
x = 0

Do While ActiveCell = Cells(3, col - 1)
    If Cells(4, col) = Cells(4, col - 1) Then
    x = x + (Cells(7, col) - Cells(34, col - 1))
    col = col + 1
    Else
    col = col + 1

    End If
    Cells(3, col).Select
Loop


MsgBox x, , "O valor de setup_g5 é"
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with time DURATION, not time of day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912568/working-with-time-duration-not-time-of-day)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Format()`

<strike>x = x + format(Cells(7, col) - Cells(34, col - 1), "hh:mm:ss")</strike>

Based on Sobigen's suggestion in comments:

```
MsgBox format(x, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), , "O valor de setup_g5 é"
```

I missed seeing that line in my initial response

Comment: Wouldn't you have to format the output in the msgbox?  I think formatting the variable would get washed out.

Answer (score 0):

The unit of the `Date` data type is 1 day. So if you want the number of minutes elapsed, you can use:

```
MsgBox x * 24 * 60
```