# Time duration, i dont understand the calculated value

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have timestamp values, but the calculated duration difference between them does not seem right.

```
Start Time, End time
23/04/2021 23:45.39.824, 23/04/2021 23:45.41.807 
24/04/2021 05:38.49.610, 24/04/2021 05:39.03.250
```

The calculated values are (roughly)

```
Start Time, End time, Duration Unformatted, Duration Formatted
23/04/2021 23:45.39.824, 23/04/2021 23:45.41.807, 2.29514E-05, 00/01/1900 00:00:01.983
24/04/2021 05:38.49.610, 24/04/2021 05:39.03.250, 0.00015787, 00/01/1900 00:00:13.640
```

The formula i used to calculate the "Duration columns is:

```
=b2-c2
```

The "Start Time" and "End Time" have the following format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000
```

**Question**

Now why does the first item have a formatted value displaying 1 second and 807 milliseconds but an unformatted value of 2.29524E-05 and the second has a 13 second and 640 millisecond with an unformatted value of 0.00015787?

I need to know this because this is messing up my calculations after the fact!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16912568/10197418

Comment: see also: [Dates And Times In Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates and times as float values in cells.
1 will translate to 1900-01-01 00:00:00.

1.5 will translate to 1900-01-01 12:00:00.

2.5 is 1900-01-02 12:00:00.

So 1 second is 1/86400 in Excel. That is why you get those small numbers in return.
You can convert the numbers too seconds by multiplying with 86400.

(I have comma as decimal point)
[image]

Comment: True... My bad.. I confused it with UNIX

Comment: it even offers nice secrets ^^ [December 30, 1899 as base date](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev)